# Which method for doing http in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

Which method for doing http calls should i use: The documenations isn’t clear ***what are the differences pros/cons of each method***

**Method 1 (as per interactive docs Lesson 2 Step 9)**

```
using import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
```

and

`import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";`

in to the app.module
similar to how its done in normal angular

**Method 2: (https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http)**

```
const httpModule = require("http");
```

and using methods such as

`httpModule.getString("https://httpbin.org/get") ...`

**Method 3 (https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-4)**

```
var fetchModule = require("fetch");
```

and using methods such as

`fetchModule.fetch(config.apiUrl + "user/" + config.appKey + "/login", { method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify({ username: viewModel.get("email"), password: viewModel.get("password") }), headers: getCommonHeaders() })`

Answer (score 1):

The first method is using Angular http *service*

Just like any service,it can be injected. Under the hood it calls lower level http calls such as fetch

The second method is using internal library called http.  Not angular's.

Third one is a lower level,promise based ,pure native impelemnation for http calls api.

It all depends on what fw you use